# React Native i18next.changeLanguage is not changing app language

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, i18next

I am trying to implement i18next library to change React Native app language, but I am not able to translate it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUBOe.png)
I have created i18n.tsx file.

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import albanian from './al.json';
import english from './en.json';

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  initImmediate: false,
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: english,
    al: albanian
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense: false
  },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
  }
});

export default i18next;
```

---

al.json

```
{
    "WelcomeTexxt": "E vleresoj qe po e shikon kete video",
    "Welcome": "Mire se vjen",
    "Museum": "Muzeuuuu",
    "welcomeBack": "MireseErdhe"
}
```

---

en.json

```
{
  "welcomeTexxt": "I really appreciate you are watching",
  "welcome": "Helloooooo",
  "museum": "ooooooooooooooooo",
  "welcomeBack": "Welcome Back 123455655"
}
```

and the translation page

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import '../lang/i18n';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import SwitchSelector from 'react-native-switch-selector';

const options = [
    {
        label: 'English',
        value: 'en'
    }, {
        label: 'Albanian',
        value: 'al'
    },
];

const LoginScreen = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    console.log(t('welcome'));

    return (
        <View style={
            {
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }
        }>
            <Text>{t('welcomeBack')}</Text>

            <SwitchSelector options={options}
                initial={0}
                 onPress= {(language) => 
                    i18n.changeLanguage(language)
                }   
            />

            <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, textAlign: 'center' }}>{t("WelcomeTexxt")}</Text>
            <Text>{
                t("Welcome")
            }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Can anyone give me any idea why i18n.changeLanguage is not working to change the language? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this updated 18n.tsx file

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import albanian from './al.json';
import english from './en.json';

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
  initImmediate: false,
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
     en: {
      translation: english, //changed here
    },
    al: {
      translation: albanian, //changed here
    },
  },
  react: {
    useSuspense: false
  },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
  }
});

export default i18next;
```

The documentation specifies that we need to pass the value of each **language key** as an **object** with *key:translation* and *value* as the *translation file*.

You have passed the translation file **directly as value**, for the language key. That's why it was not able to recognise the files to use for translation :)

Comment: thank you very very much. Your solution already works :D :D :D

Comment: You’re welcome , I’ve made this mistake countless times. Glad to know I’m not the only one 

Answer (score -1):

May you can try with withTranslation like below:

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import '../lang/i18n';
import { useTranslation, withTranslation  } from 'react-i18next';
import SwitchSelector from 'react-native-switch-selector';

const options = [
    {
        label: 'English',
        value: 'en'
    }, {
        label: 'Albanian',
        value: 'al'
    },
];

const LoginScreen = () => {
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    console.log(t('welcome'));

    return (
        <View style={
            {
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }
        }>
            <Text>{t('welcomeBack')}</Text>

            <SwitchSelector options={options}
                initial={0}
                 onPress= {(language) => 
                    i18n.changeLanguage(language)
                }   
            />

            <Text style={{ fontSize: 26, textAlign: 'center' }}>{t("WelcomeTexxt")}</Text>
            <Text>{
                t("Welcome")
            }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default withTranslation()(LoginScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jayesh but unfortunately is not working again.